# $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ aree the only holomorphic extensions of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The question is in the title, is an exercise of a textbook of Complex Analysis. I'm having some problems due to singularities on the classical functions: There is a theorem that states:

> If $a$ is a isolated singularity of $f$ and $\lim_{z \to a}(z-a)f(z) = 0$, then there is a unique holomorphic extension to the point $a$.

The real deal here is: The classical trigonometric functions don't have this kind of isolated singularity, so, how can I proceed to prove this statement. Also, the question "extends" to prove the same for the hyperbolic trigonometric functions, as well as the power function, so, probrably there is some pattern here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that you are overthinking the problem. This has nothing to do with singularities. You only need the identity theorem for holomorphic functions.

Comment: It follows from the so called identity theorem. If $G$ is a domain (open and connected) and two holomorphic functions $f,g:G\to\mathbb{C}$ agree on a subset $A\subseteq G$ which contains an accumulation point then $f=g$. Now, $\mathbb{R}$ obviously contains accumulation points, so the standard real functions can have at most one analytic extension.

Comment: How do you define $\cos z$? as a power series or as $\frac{e^{iz}+e^{iz}}{2}$. In any event, if $C$ is another extension of $\cos$ (defined in the real line), then it coincides on $\mathbb{R}$which has limit points; hence $C=\cos$ in $\mathbb{C}$. If $f$ is analytic in a domain $D$ and $f=0$ in $A\subset D$ and $A$ has limit points in $D$, then $f=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the identity theorem. Let $f\colon\Bbb C\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ be a holomorohic function such that $(\forall x\in\Bbb R):f(x)=\cos(x)$. Can it be distinct from the (complex) cosine function. No, because $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid f(z)=\cos(z)\}\supset\Bbb R$, whis has non-isolated points.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I think the textbook doesn't has this theorem so I'll prove it to be able to use it!